# Getting recently viewed video from DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

HI I am working on website that supports videos and images displayed on it .
I need to make a functionality to get the recently viewed videos of a particular user .

I have the following table structure from where i am getting the no of views of the particular video that how many people have viewed it .(by fetching no of rows corresponding to the same **video id**  ) .

```
view_id user_email             video_id
      3 singhmakhan24gmail.com       24
    130 singhmakhan24gmail.com       60
      8 singhmakhan24gmaii com       27
     10 singhmakhan24gmail.com       30
```

Now What modification should be made in the table structure to fetch the recently viewed videos of a particular **USER ID** .

I think the timestamp would also be required to get this .
Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: You'll need to join with the table that contains your users, probably by using the user_email as a key. And you'll need to add a datetime/timestamp row so you can get views for a specific period.

Comment: Why do you have emails in the table of views? You should put a user_id in this table, and put the email in the user table.

Comment: ya i will use the user ID instead thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally specking, you need 3 tables to achive your needs as follows

```
user_tbl(user_id, user_email, ...);
video_tbl(video_id, video_name, ...);
user_video_view(user_id, video_id, view_date);
```

particular user can view many video, and video can be shown by many times. relationship between tables as follows

```
user_tbl : user_video_view = 1 : N
user_video_view : video_tbl = N :1
```

to obtain how many people have viewed particular video. (you've already done)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user_video_view
WHERE video_id = ?;
```

to fetch the recently viewed videos of a particular USER ID

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user_video_view
WHERE user_id = ?
ORDER BY view_date DESC
```

your question.

> *I think the timestamp would also be required to get this*

YES!!! like view_date

Comment: that thing i have already implemented that how many people have viewd the particular video .

Comment: @RanbirSingh I'm not sure you have designed similar mine. You just posted SELECT output not database schema. can you post your schema? Tables and their columns.

Comment: I need to make it as the recently viewed videos by a particular user .let me check with the table schema and query just one sec please

Answer (score 0):

Put a `CREATED_DATE_TIME` column and query for the most recent one

Comment: And how does that get him a user id ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add a column ViewedDateTime column with data type DateTime. Insert the view date and time.